# redirect()->route laravel return html not go to function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-response

I need to build a personaliced response to get one URL returned from API. In my function store i´m saving all data in my db ok. I have a personaliced class that this class have any method to connect API and return response, etc. In my function store, i have this call:

```
return redirect()->route('commercialautograph.precontract', ['precontract' => $precontract]);
```

This call return response from API:

```
$response = $this->client->request('POST', $url, [
            'auth' => [config("viafirma.apiKey.username"), config("viafirma.apiKey.password")],
            'json' => $json
        ]);
                        
        return $response;
```

if i build mehtod in my controller to get link from API, return BASE64´s pdf that i i´m sending to API. that's why i´m building redirect to other route, to close other operations. But my problem it´s that when i´m doing redirect, laravel returned me HTML:

```
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n    <html lang="en">\r\n        <he…\n\r\n        </div>\r\n        \r\n    </body>\r\n</html>', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

This example it´s a webrowser console.

My route is:

```
Route::prefix('commercial')->name('commercial')->group(function(){
  Route::get('autograph/{precontract}', [CommercialPreContractController::class, 'autograph'])->name('autograph.precontract');
}
```

this route call other function in my same controller, that in this moment i want to arrive to function:

```
/**
     * Function to digital signature precontract
     */
    public function autograph(Array $precontract)
    {
        echo "llego¿?";
        exit();
        try{
```

I haven´t got any problem in logs.. And i don´t know that i´m doing wrong, but i can´t arrive to my function. I can´t to do `$this->autograph` beacause i need return response from API and read it in `VUE js`

I hope that anybody can help me.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks you very much for readme.

route list:

```
GET|HEAD        commercial/autograph/{precontract} commercialautograph.precontract › Commercial\CommercialPreContractCont…
```

Comment: You question is incomprehensible. You have to describe better what you want to achieve, what you have implemented and what is your problem, otherwise it will hard for anyone to help you. Show the result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: So I spent some time reading the post and trying to figure out the process or the logic you're using. This is my conclusion:
`1) A user submits a form with a PDF file.` 
    `2) The controller encodes the PDF content in BASE64.` 
    `3) An API request is sent with the BASE64-encoded PDF, along with authentication (user/password).` 
    `4) The API authenticates the request, saves the BASE64 PDF, and processes it on the server.` 
    `5) The API responds by providing a link.` 
    `6) The controller extracts the link from the API response ($response).`

Comment: `7) A redirection to another route occurs.`  `8) The target route's controller method is executed, handling the link and rendering an HTML view or performing other actions as needed.`  Is it accurate?

Comment: @haruk1515 yes, it´s exactly

Comment: @Theofanis i updated my question with my route defined

Comment: @scorpions77 Your Laravel code defines a route named called `autograph.precontract`, however `php artisan route:list` shows `commercialautograph.precontract`.
Is there another route with the name `commercialautograph.precontract` in your application?

Check that you're using the correct route name when using `return redirect()->...`.
Maybe instead of using `return redirect('commercialautograph.precontract')->...` you need to use `return redirect('autograph.precontract')->...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send array of data as path parameters, it will not be mapped to any route. This will not work with any route method POST, GET, etc.

Remove `{precontact}` from path param, give it a static name e.g. `commercial/autograph/precontact` so this will be a static route. Send to that endpoint specific query (GET) parameters e.g. id, name `?id=...&name=...` etc.

Also `public function autograph(Array $precontract)` does not work for any kind of data. `Array $precontract` is invalid for controllers in Laravel. It should be replaced with `public function autograph(Request $request)` see laravel docs. From there get the params like `$request->input('id')`.

So after all these the redirect command will be

```php
return redirect()->route('commercialautograph.precontract', ['id' => $precontract['id'], 'name' => $precontract['name']);
```